# Is IBus Necessary on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ibus

So it appears that IBus is started by default on Saucy, but unfortunately this is leading to problems with my IntelliJ installation as per this bug:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

So my question is: would disabling IBus cause any problems? It appears its for multilingual keyboard support which is not necessary for me as I am just using default en keyboard layout.

Comment: I suggest you try something like this guy who cant play minecraft due to it having problems with iBus, he uses a script that temporarily disables iBus then turns it back on once he closes the game.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1612164

Comment: @aledujke Its a nice thought, but this is a development machine so my IDE is always open. My concern is that other programs will misbehave if I do turn off IBus. Using an IDE is not like playing a full screen video game. I often am moving around to dozens of different programs every day while my IDE is still open.

Comment: Well I meant that you can try and run the IDE for a day or two like this and see if there are any problems. It looks like you are afraid of just trying it out yourself... Is there a reason why you cant try and disable it? I mean... if there are problems just turn it back on.

Comment: @aledujke Of course I could just do that, but the point of the question is two fold: 1) Find out more about what IBus does 2) Gauge the probability of there being a problem if I disable IBus. I don't even know what sort of "problems" would develop. If its something like forcing me to restart my machine that is a problem because I am not looking to lose any work or time on this issue. I would just continue quitting IntelliJ (mouse still works, even when typing stops) and restarting it. It solves the problem and is just a minor pain in the ass. I appreciate the link however, so thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you don't use different keyboard layouts (or need to type in a phonetic language such as Japanese using English letters) then it is not necessary.  There may be a few programs that for some reason require it, but if they do you can simply reinstall it. I would suggest you go ahead and remove it. If there are problems it's easy enough to undo, but I would guess that everything will work fine.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge ibus` ~> the following packages will be REMOVED: `ibus* unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon*`